# Sequelize altering all table fields to snake case

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

im trying to make a migration to alter all existing table fields to snake case, and future ones to be already written that way. 
Up to now i've been doing this with

```
myTableField = {type: datatype.stmh, field: 'my_table_field'}
```

thing is i wanna stop doing this and for further upcoming fields i just need them to be set up directly with snake case.

Is there any way of doing this ? or i have to manually run an alter field for each?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to not rename every field to underscored in the model definition, via the underscored model option.

```
options.underscored - Converts all camelCased columns to underscored if true
options.underscoredAll - Converts camelCased model names to underscored table names if true
```

ex:

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
               firstname: Sequelize.STRING,
               lastname: Sequelize.STRING
             },{ 
                underscored:true})
```

Also on the CLI, we have the option to generate migrations with snakecase

```
>> sequelize model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string  --underscored
```

where

```
 --underscored      Use snake case for the timestamp's attribute names
```

But it only does it for the timestamp fields on the migration defs.